# Rest Easy ClientResponse cannot find symbol releaseConnection()

Tags: resteasy

I was trying to release the resources after using the Response and I was using org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponse for the same.
My code is as follows.

```
    ClientResponse<String> response = null;
    final ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(urlString);\\thiscontains username and password
    request.accept(acceptType);
    if (body != null) {
    request.body(consumesType, body);
}
request.header("Content-Type", consumesType);
        try {

            restClientService.addAuthenticationHeaders(request,
                    userName, password);
            response = restClientService.get(request);
            if (response.getStatus() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error occured");
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (response != null) {
                response.releaseConnection();
            }
        }
```

I am facing the below error message when I am building the above code using ant

```
  [javac] C:\workspace\com\session\impl\DataSyncJobHelperBean.java:101:    cannot find symbol
  [javac] symbol  : method releaseConnection()
  [javac] location: class org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponse<java.lang.String>
  [javac]                             response.releaseConnection();
  [javac]                                     ^
```

Please provide any inputs if I am missing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this.

Actually in my resteasy lib folder I have two different versions of jars i.e 
  “resteasy-jaxrs” and “resteasy-jaxrs-2.0.1.GA” and the method     “response.releaseConnection()” was introduced at rest easy 1.1.1.GA, while doing   build it is loading from resteasy-jaxrs.jar. So the build is failing.

I deleted the “resteasy-jaxrs.jar” file from all the locations in work space and now we are able to run the build successfully.